# Именованные url в django

Tags: python, django

Есть два приложения, у каждого есть схема url. Можно ли задать одинаковые имена некоторым урлам в этих приложениях, и если да, то как потом к ним обращаться в шаблонах?

Есть некий шаблон, который используется вьюхами из первого приложения и из второго приложения. И вот в этот шаблон хочется поместить именованный урл, т.е. написать просто

```
{% url my_named_url %}
```

но если я укажу namespace-ы при подключении схем url, то это работать не будет. Может как-то можно получить название текущего приложения внутри шаблона, чтобы сделать как-то так

```
{% url current_app:my_named_url %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из соответсвующей вьюхи передавайте в шаблон url как переменную. Пусть логика лежит на вьюхах, как и положено, а не на шаблонах.

Либо - свой template tag, который делает `reverse` и возвращает результат.